# get cell element from R read.csv object?

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

In R, I'm trying to get a cell value from a `read.csv` object. But this is what I get:

```
a<- tail(sp.csv, n=1L)
a$V1
[1] 5042951
54 Levels: 11054 1156785) 1157947) 1159014) 1166898) 1174855) ... src,trg,sp_len,hops
```

Where, sp.csv is the read.csv object variable.  Even if I try variants like: `a$V1[[1]]` or `a[['V1']][1]` what am I doing wrong, any suggestions?  What I need is the values from V1 and V2.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly isn't working? The output seems correct to me. The reasons you have levels there is because `V1` is a `factor`.

Comment: I think I figured my error, I did this: `sp.csv <-data.frame(read.csv(file, header=F, sep="\t"))` if I remove the conversion to a data.frame, I can access the individual cell value.  I need to read about `factor` in R.

Comment: @sAguinaga  You can use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `read.csv`, to get the non-numeric column as character column.  It seems to me that it is a numeric column, but there are some elements in that column that make it non-numeric.  Check your dataset to find any non-numeric elements and then specify `na.strings=` in the read.csv

Comment: Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` with `data.frame` or `read.csv`